How to use the Vue3 runtime-only build with Symfony 7
I'm trying to use the the runtime-only build of vue3 with Symfony 7. To do this, I followed the Symfony documentation (except for that I use vue version 3 instead of 2, which is the default). Then I disabled the vue build with the included compiler in my webpack.config.js:
Encore
    // ... zip ...
    .enableVueLoader(() => {}, {
        runtimeCompilerBuild: false,
        version: 3
    })

After that my components stopped working. And I got the following error in the dev-console:
[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js". 
  at <App>

I think the problem is how I mount the app into the DOM, but I couln't find any example on how to do it correctly with Symfony (+Encore). At the moment I have the following two components:

Hello.vue

<template>
   <div>
       <p>Hello Worlds!</p>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       name: "hello"
   }
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>


App.vue

<script>
import Hello from './Hello'

export default {
    components: {
        Hello
    }
}
</script>

The latter is imported in my app.js-file and mounted to an element in the DOM:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './components/App'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

The rest is also just following the Symfony documentation, where one has to create a template and import the js there:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text><text y=%221.3em%22 x=%220.2em%22 font-size=%2276%22 fill=%22%23fff%22>sf</text></svg>">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">
           <hello></hello>
           {% block body %}{% endblock %}
       </div>
    </body>
</html>

(Actually I wouldn't need a template at all, if I could make it work without one.)
This all works when setting runtimeCompilerBuild to true. But how can I make it work with runtimeCompilerBuild set to false?
